# golang: serving net.Conn using a gin router

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a function that handles an incoming TCP connection:

```golang
func Handle(conn net.Conn) error {
    // ...
}
```

Also, I have an initialized gin router with implemented handles:

```golang
router := gin.New()
router.GET(...)
router.POST(...)
```

The `router.Run(addr)` call will start a separate HTTP server on the `addr`.

Is there any way to handle incoming connections inside the `Handle` function using this router without running a separate HTTP server?

Comment: No. By the time Gin is doing anything, it's already started handling the HTTP request (or failed it for being an invalid HTTP request). You could do the reverse, and have your TCP handler take all connections, determine if they should be handled by Gin by some logic, and then kick off the HTTP stack, but it would be complex and likely bug-prone. The cleanest solution here is to listen on two ports, one for HTTP and one for whatever you're doing with raw TCP.

Comment: @BaytaDarell My app is listening to several hundred ports, let's say 9500-10000. Each new conn is passed to a separate subservice that is mapped to one or more ports and handles conns in its own manner. Now I'm trying to create a subservice that will act as an HTTP server and handle conns from several tens of ports. I already have gin handlers and I just want to use them to build this subservice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [net.Listener](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listener) implementation that accepts connections by receiving on a channel:

```
type listener struct {
    ch   chan net.Conn
    addr net.Addr
}

// newListener creates a channel listener. The addr argument
// is the listener's network address.
func newListener(addr net.Addr) *listener {
    return &listener{
        ch:   make(chan net.Conn),
        addr: addr,
    }
}

func (l *listener) Accept() (net.Conn, error) {
    c, ok := <-l.ch
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("closed")
    }
    return c, nil
}

func (l *listener) Close() error { return nil }

func (l *listener) Addr() net.Addr { return l.addr }
```

Handle connections by sending to the channel:

```
func (l *listener) Handle(c net.Conn) error {
    l.ch <- c
    return nil
}
```

Here's how to tie it all together:

- Create the listener:

  ```
    s := newListener(someAddr)
  ```
- Configure the Gin engine as usual.

  ```
    router := gin.New()
    router.GET(...)
    router.POST(...)
  ```
- Run the net/http server in a goroutine using the channel listener and the Gin engine:

  ```
    err := http.Serve(s, router)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
  ```
- In your dispatching code, call the `s.Handle(c)` to pass the connection to the net/http server and then on to the Gin engine.

Comment: While this solution did not solve my particular case, this IS the working solution, so I accepted it. Well done and thank you!

Comment: But how would you pass the actual net.Conn to the Gin  instance?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a similar task - handle TCP connections from multiple ports using a single router, here's a workaround that I eventually found. Instead of running an HTTP server on a port, I run it with a UNIX socket using `router.RunUnix(socketName)`. The full solution consists of three steps:

1. Run a HTTP server to listen through a UNIX socket using `router.RunUnix(socketName)`
2. Inside the `Handle` function read the incoming bytes from the connection and send them to the socket. After that, read the HTTP response from the socket and write it into the connection.
3. Close the connection.

Comment: if using docker then same can be done by mounting container port to multiple host ports, another way of doing would be using iptable, these our other few ways which don't require multiple application deployment with different ports