# How to read the raw TCP payload of a TLS client hello message in gin?

Tags: go

I'm using gin as an HTTP API endpoint server.
I need to read the raw TCP/UDP payload of any SSL/TLS client hello message coming into my server for analysis purposes.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: I would flag it as duplicate but I cannot because there is a bounty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148822/golang-serving-net-conn-using-a-gin-router

Comment: This looks like a duplicate + isn't really what would be considered a _good_ question. There's no code here, nothing to show us what you've tried already, and why it didn't work as expected.